# data realted access in authenciation

Tags: authentication, spring-security, role-base-authorization

I am build a web application,and there are some operations is protected for identified people.

I use the sping security for access control,however I have no idea how to control them when deep to the data level.

For exmaple,there are two operation `list` and `edit` operation.

Both the `administrator of the company` and the `administrator of one department` can access these operations,but the data they can 'list' or 'edit' are not the same.

`administrator of the company` can get access to all the data of the company while `administrator of one department` can only get access to the data of his/her department.

So I wonder what is the best practice to implement these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most easy method - use PostFilter annotation on service layer.

```java
@Transactional(readonly=true)
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'edit')")
List<DepartamentData> getDepartamenData();

@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#data, 'edit')")
List<DepartamentData> editDepartamenData(DepartamentData data);
```

Or another example:

```java
@Transactional(readonly=true)
@PostFilter(
  "   hasRole('company_admin')" +
  "|| (hasRole('departament_admin') && filterObject.departament.equals(principal.departament))")
List<DepartamentData> getDepartamenData();
```